# Angular 6 I can't use ngModel with input tag

Tags: angular, webpack

i'm using angular 6 and i want to use ngModel:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="textValue">
```

so i get this error:

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'
```

i try adding forms module to my login.module.ts 
 but i get an error with webpack :

```
Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

and my dependencies are :

```
"@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^6.0.0"
```

What should I do to get mgModel working on Angular 6?

Comment: Make sure you've got `FormsModule` in the imports array of your module, such as `app.module.ts`. Which line is causing the error about `Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`?

Comment: this is my code of login.module.ts

`import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule,LoginRoutingModule,FormsModule],
    declarations: [LoginComponent]
})`
the error is with webpack i think

Comment: Are you able to create a StackBlitz that reproduces the problem?

Comment: It's the first time  i heard about it

Comment: @falhmed can you please edit your post, and add your app.module.ts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please include the following in your `app.module.ts`:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [FormsModule]
})
```

If you did not include in @NgModule, you will get the above error